# Non-blocking UIView animated scaling

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, block, calayer

I'd like to animate scaling a UIView and all of its content in a non blocking way. Currently I do this ...

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1,1.1);
            self.view.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

However it is **blocking**. I would rather use something like ...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1,1.1);
                self.view.transform = transform;
                     }];
```

... but animateWithDuration doesn't to work with CALayer/CGAffineTransform transformation. How can I achieve the same animation without blocking anything?

Comment: maybe just manually change the size and origin of the views frame, instead of using a transform, bit more handy work but it should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
 animations:^{
   CGAffineTransform transform =
     CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2.0, 2.0);
 self.view.transform = transform;
 }];
```

---

Just adding a useful note to this great answer, almost always you want to turn on rasterisation, so it looks smooth

```
self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
 animations:^{
   CGAffineTransform transform =
     CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.5, 0.5);
 self.view.transform = transform;
 }];
```